# Why can't we destruct objet and in order to create new variable : JS

Tags: javascript, destructuring

Can someone explain me the reason why :

```
const param = {hello: "Hello", world: "world", name: "Patrick"}
const variable = {hello, world} = param;
```

Will set my `variable` to :

```
{hello: "Hello", world: "world", name: "Patrick"}
```

And not

```
{hello: "Hello", world: "world"}
```

Or even `undefined` why taking this choice ?

I'm curious !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of an assignment expression is the right-hand side of the assignment. So `{hello, world} = param` performs a destructuring assignment to `hello` and `world`, but its value is the entire `param` object. This is then used as the value in the initialization of `variable`. So it's effectively equivalent to:

```
const variable = (hello = param.hello, world = param.world, param);
```

Note also that you're not declaring the `hello` and `world` variables, these are just being assigned. They'll be global variables if they're not previously declared in the scope.